# Upgrading from Play 2.6 to 2.7: How to refactor this Play.current statement to use DI

Tags: dependency-injection, java-8, playframework, global-variables

In my Java 8 Play 2.6 application I have this particular line in a MessageConsumer class that reads a "Rule" record in the DB and sends the JSON message (`node`) to a specific processor based on the type configured on the rule column. `ProcessType` is an enum of Sub Classes that all extend from a base (Super class) process.

```
Play.current().injector().instanceOf(ProcessType.getClass(matchingRule.getProcessType())).processMessage(node, matchingRule);
```

I'm having trouble figuring out how to refactor this and don't want to add the `allowGlobalApplication = true` config parameter if I can avoid it.

Answer (score 0):

The most straightforward approach is to inject the `Injector` into the component that contains this call (the `MessageConsumer`). This can be done the same way as any other Play component.

You can also inject the `Application` instance, which would return the same thing as `Play.current()`. This could be useful if you need more information from the `Application` object, but if not, injecting the `Injector` directly would be preferable, as it would create less coupling between the `MessageConsumer` and other components.

This assumes that the `MessageConsumer` is created by DI itself. If not, please add more details to the question, including the context code.